# Regular expression to search for a specific string along with unknowns

Tags: php, regex

Im attepting to find the regex to pull the

```
 http://{any_string}.blogspot.com/feeds/{any_string}/comments/default
```

out of

```
 <link rel="alternate"
 type="application/atom+xml"
 title="{any_string}"
 href="http://{any_string}.blogspot.com/feeds/{any_string}/comments/default"
 />
```

I know basics of regex and using eregi but im unsure of how to include constant characters such as the http://, etc in the regex expression!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Characters just match themselves (except some special ones like dot and backslash):

```
http://\S+\.blogspot\.com/feeds/\S+/comments/default
```

As pointed out, with php's preg_match, you may have to escape the solidii:

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/\S+\.blogspot\.com\/feeds\/\S+\/comments\/default/", string_to_match_against);
```

Comment: You would either need to escape the `/` or use different delimiters in the preg_match call.

Comment: You need to escape the full stops.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: Sure, but that's not really to do with the regex, but how it's encoded in the host language.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://.*\.blogspot\.com/feeds.*/comments/default
```

Where . matches newlines